# VF Remoting and WF Rules

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

Why would I not see WF Rule execution in a VF Remoting log?  There is an external app we installed that has a page that uses VF Remoting.  I'm trying to figure out order-of-execution for their particular app so I can figure out whether to build using WF Rule or Trigger, but when I check the debug logs, I only see the trigger details, not the WF Rule details...  Is this just because it's an installed package?

Comment: Is that a managed package? If so, it's logs will not be visible I guess.

Comment: I thought the things triggered by it (the Workflow Rules that I built) would show up, even if their specific debug code was hidden...